# PHP Return by Reference Clarification

Tags: php

I have an example script here with a return by reference magic __get:

```
class a{

    public $_attributes = array();

    function &__get($k){
        if(isset($this->_attributes[$k])){
            return $this->_attributes[$k];
        }else{
            return null;
        }
    }

    function __set($k, $v){
        $this->_attributes[$k] = $v;
    }
}


$a = new a();
$a->username = "sam";
var_dump($a->username);
$u = $a->username;
$u = $u.'dddd';
var_dump($a->username);
var_dump($u);
```

The idea of returning by reference from my __get here is so I can do stuff like:

```
    $this->user->ins[session_id()] = array(
        "key"=>$_SESSION['server_key'],
        "ip"=>$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'],
        "agent"=>$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],
        "last_request"=>$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],
        "last_active"=>new MongoDate(),
    );
```

Since I cannot normally due to PHP using a copy of the original array. However When I pull say "username" into a new variable ($u) I do not want it to pass a reference of its original parent.

The script above prints out:

```
string(3) "sam" string(3) "sam" string(7) "samdddd"
```

Which is awesome becasue it is not passing $username as reference back to $u and it works like I want it to.

Now time for the question: Is this a good approach? Is it expected behaviour in PHP to do this?

I have been reading the page for referencing but it's a bit patchy, however it does mention that to tell PHP that $u should be a reference I must also use the reference symbol when pulling out the variable (as can be seen here: http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.return.php).

So is this expected behaviour and can I rely on it in PHP or is there something terrible I'm not seeing?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Now time for the question: Is this a good approach? Is it expected
>   behaviour in PHP to do this?

This is a bad (odd) approach. Simply manipulate the object, this is more common practice. The way you have it is tricky and can mislead you during development.

If you decide to continue with your reference approach, you need to make sure you received the value by reference. See sample below:

```
$a = new a();
// returning by reference is not enough, you need to receive by ref as well
$u =& $a->username;
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of returning an array by reference, just return an `ArrayObject`.

```
class Foo
{
  private $data;

  public function __construct()
  {
    $this->data = new ArrayObject();
  }

  public function __get($key)
  {
    return $this->data;
  }
}

$foo = new Foo();
$foo->data['bar'] = 42;
var_dump($foo->data);
```

Output:

```
object(ArrayObject)#2 (1) {
  ["storage":"ArrayObject":private]=>
  array(1) {
    ["bar"]=>
    int(42)
  }
}
```

Unfortunately PHP `ArrayObject`s cannot be used directly with PHP array functions, but I would prefer the above over always returning `__get` by reference.

You can do something similar for scalars if you box them in an object that implements `__toString()`. And yes, there are flaws with this as well, but I would always discourage using `__get` by reference.

Comment: This would work in most cases without the context I was using it in, which now that I look at the first answer I think I should have added context. Imagine you are building an active record model, so you want all the functions of active record but your building for NoSQL which means dynamic shcema so you think you need a $data attribute since you cant just say "get fields" like in SQL. This is where my question originally came from. Passing down by reference in __get allowed me to manipulate a dynamic schema like the actual object but have all its functions as well.

Comment: I mean as an alternative you can house a $_fields array which holds the key => name of all fields within the dynamic object and that is prolly the best way cos you can manipulate the object itself while ascertaining a dynamic set of schema recorded by variable name witin the $_fields array.